# Retrieve data from Salesforce using eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I need to retrieve data from salesforce using the eclipse, but I had a problem when I tried this.

I am using a newest version of eclipse (Neon [Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)] and Kepler [Version: Kepler Service Release 2]) with the force.com library installed.

I do these steps:
1- In the Package Explorer, right click -> New -> Project -> Force.com Project -> Next
2- I create the new project by filling these fields (Project Name, Username, password, Security Token, Environment) -> Next -> then the package is fetched
3- I select Selected metadata components -> I click the button Choose... (It takes a lot of time to open the components) -> then I choose for example 1 class from classes and I click ok.
4- It takes a lot of time and a dialog appear:
[image]
5- I click again on continue, the issue persist and the same dialog appear again many times.
I search for the error I found that I should increase the size of Xmx in eclipse.ini:
[image]

I had the same error.
6- Then I click finish to retrieve the class, the operation take a long time in a progress status, and finally nothing happened.

Somebody can help me in this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using this link : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Why-does-the-Force-com-IDE-time-out-or-display-a-Java-heap-size-error-when-I-m-building-a-new-project&language=en_US

Comment: check the API version of the Force.com plugin you tried to install...try older version (30.0)...

Answer (score 0):

you was trying to deploy a bulk of code , and you was constantly facing the administrator lock out & would have to wait the 2hrs before we can deploy again,another was the fetch cycle time out .So when contacted Salesforce we were informed “Fetch Cycle Limit Reached” error,  is an internal Eclipse IDE error. Since every deployment requires all the test classes in the org to be run,hitting the Fetch cycle causes administration setup permissions to hang and lock.So the alternate method was using change sets . Though the deployment takes longer the advantage is that it does not have the fetch cycle limit .

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000094EUIAY

Comment: Is this intended to be an answer?

Comment: It is not my case

Comment: Because in the case above they deploy from eclipse to Salesforce, but my need is to deploy from Salesforce (Force.com) to eclipse. Anyway thank you a lot @user39251 for your help